# MarkLogic - Database size units

Tags: marklogic-9

I am using below query to return the size of each database in MarkLogic server. The query is returning data but not sure what units (KB/MB/GB etc) the query is returning. I tried to find approximate size of each collection manually to add up, but somehow the numbers are not matching. Does MarkLogic apply compression by default on the documents?

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare namespace forest = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/forest";

for $db-id in xdmp:databases()
let $db-name := xdmp:database-name($db-id)
let $db-size :=
  fn:sum(
    for $f-id in xdmp:database-forests($db-id)
    let $f-status := xdmp:forest-status($f-id)
    let $space := $f-status/forest:device-space
    let $f-name := $f-status/forest:forest-name
    let $f-size :=
      fn:sum(
        for $stand in $f-status/forest:stands/forest:stand
        let $stand-size := $stand/forest:disk-size/fn:data(.)
        return $stand-size
      )
    return $f-size
  )
order by $db-size descending
return $db-name || " = " || $db-size
```

Answer (score 0):

The measure of unit shown in Admin UI on the Cluster Status page is always MB, and the numbers shown there match what your code returns.

MarkLogic doesn't really apply compression, but it does have complex logic to take data, and structure information apart for each document. There is some gain when you have repetition in your documents. The more repetition, which also includes element names, the larger the difference.

HTH!